# Network and firewall

Tags: networking

I have server 2008 and Watchguard Firewall. The server ip is 10.0.0.2 and watchgaurd firewall ip is 10.0.0.1.The firewall default ip is 10.0.0.1 and its subnet is 255.255.254.0. We have around 500 users they get their IP from watchgaurd firewall so what should be server 2008 subnet and default gateway so that the users can access the server 2008 for file sharing and printer.

Comment: Edit your question and clarify it.  Paragraphs will help

Answer (score 0):

The server's subnet mask and gateway should be the *same* as that used by the client computers it is serving.

It sounds like your WatchGuard firewall is acting as your network DHCP server, in which case you need to make sure the IP address of the server is not in the DHCP pool (i.e. range of addresses the firewall can assign to clients).